# hibernate criteria: havin count(.), in

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-criteria

I have a manyToMany relationship between articles and tags,
and now need to make something like this:

```
  select * from article where count(article.tags in someListOfTags ) >= n
```

how can I do this with hibernate criteria??

Thanks for all tips :)

I'm using hibernate 4.1.1

Comment: solution: http://fokot.blogspot.de/2011/06/having-clause-in-hibernate-criteria-no.html